# Why kotlin split() and map(String::toInt) on empty string gets NumberFormatException?

Tags: string, kotlin, split

Below kotlin code throws the exception.

```
"".split(";").map(String::toInt)

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

I could not figure the reason since the "".split(";") would return an empyt list that should not call map's callback function.

So, I did some experiments in Kotlin REPL, map on emptyList runs okay.

```
"".split(";")
res60: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.String> = []

listOf<String>().map(String::toInt)
res61: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Int> = []
```

Can anyone give me a clue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The list returned by `split` will always have at least one element. If the delimiter doesn't appear in the String, the returned list will just have the original String in it. It will never return an empty list.

Comment: You are right, test this code in REPL "".split(";").size and gets result: res68: kotlin.Int = 1

Answer (score 1):

Like Tenfour04 says, the list isn't empty - I'm posting this as an answer so I can do the formatting, but:

```
println("Empty list: " + listOf<String>())
println("Single empty string: " + listOf(""))
println("Split empty string, plus an extra empty string: " + "".split(';').plus(""))
```

gives you

```
Empty list: []
Single empty string: []
Split empty string, plus an extra empty string: [, ]
```

yeah that's not exactly helpful output

Comment: Yeah, the node.js seems gives better result when list containing empty string:
"".split(',')   which outpus: [ '' ]

Comment: Better is subjective. This is a strongly typed language, without blurry lines between what is empty, null, 0, false or non-existent. It would be poor design for a strongly typed language to decide for your that your empty string should just be erased.

Comment: @Tenfour04 in the case of this output though, that's exactly what's happening! I agree that seeing some empty quotes would be better than literally nothing